# Not submiting when I add a form inside another form

Tags: php, html

I have this structure in my page. Secondary form works, and main does not. When I remove secondary, then MAIN works. I would like to keep them both in this structure because I ended my code. Is there any way to manage it? Thank you!

```
<form name="main" action="result.php" method="post">
. // this form submits some results to result.php
.
. 
<form name="secondary" ........>
.
. //this is an ajax form that uploads an image to the server
</form>
.
.
.
<input button>
</form>
```

Comment: Nested forms are not allowed in (x)HTML.

Comment: Why don't you just position the second form over the first form and not include it. Including it into the first form will not work. And if you submit the second form using AJAX you don't even need to have a second form. Just select the form elements you want to submit using JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible like that, sorry: **that is not valid markup** - HTML forms do not allow nesting. I'm sorry if that's inconvenient; as it stands, this will only break in various interesting ways in different browsers, and definitely will not do what you intended.

On a more positive note: the final goal you want is achievable, albeit in different ways:

- do the image and form processing in one form (not entirely convenient, I admit)
- have the "inner form" as an IFRAME
- send "inner form" via AJAX:

  - the "inner form" is not a `<form>`, maybe just a `<fieldset>`?
  - it has an input button, which launches a JS method which sends the data from the "inner form" via AJAX
  - the "outer form" is an actual `<form>`; before it's submitted, it clears the contents of the "inner form", so the "inner form" fields aren't submitted with "outer form"
  - this will break without JavaScript
- have the "inner form" outside the "outer form" HTML, position them with CSS (so it appears to be "outer" and "inner", when it's actually "form #1" and "form #2") - as suggested by [@Kau-Boy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299375/kau-boy) in the comments

  - this would probably look strange in screen-readers etc, but it would be the cleanest approach IMO